# How can I remove my stuck freewheel?

Tags: mountain-bike, freewheel, rear-wheel, tools, axle

I have been trying for days to remove my freewheel using a freewheel tool. I have been using an adjustable spanner for now but it still is not moving. Am I not strong enough? Or is there another trick that I can use?[image]

Any assistance is required as I have been stuck for days. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Take off the axle nut, slide on the freewheel tool, and replace the nut so that it holds the freewheel tool in place.
2. Lock the freewheel tool in a bench vise.
3. Grasp the wheel at the rim and turn counter-clockwise to unscrew.

This gives you more leverage and control than a wrench.

Comment: The bench vice needs to be bolted to a bench that's either bolted to the floor or is large/heavy enough to take the force.

Comment: @DavidD or sit on the workbench while turning the wheel

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to grasp and turn the wheel itself, rather than turning the freewheel tool. This gives greater mechanical advantage, since the wheel’s radius is (probably) longer than your wrench.

Of course, something needs to hold the freewheel tool fixed in place while you grab and turn the wheel. One option is to tighten the freewheel tool into a bench vise. If you don’t have a bench vise, I’ve had luck fitting an adjustable wrench on the freewheel tool and jamming the wrench against something fixed, so the wrench doesn’t move.  Maybe the wall, or a railing.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling for some time to remove the freewheel from my single speed MTB, it had been on the bike for over 20 years and even with a large adjustable spanner and the correct removal tool securely bolted in place I could not shift it. As I didn't have a bench vice or a length of pipe to hand I tried this method. I got an assistant (my 12 year old grandson) to hold the wheel upright on the ground with the tire butted against the wall so it would not roll. I placed the spanner so it was approximately horizontal and pointing to the left of the hub, and then stood on it with one foot. That did the trick! The freewheel moved enough to loosen it and then i just used the spanner by hand. I may not be that strong anymore but I'm certainly heavy enough these days.